# Integrating Localytics - FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Trying to integrate Localytics, step 6 assumes you extend `FragmentActivity`:

```
In onResume, open a session, start an upload, and register the activity for marketing.
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Localytics.openSession();
    Localytics.upload();

    if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity)
    {
        Localytics.setInAppMessageDisplayActivity((FragmentActivity) activity);
    }

    Localytics.handleTestMode(activity.getIntent());
}
```

In my class, `MainActivity.java`, we're extending a class that extends a class that extends a few more classes, finally ending with class that extend `FragmentActivity`. This is causing the following exception in `MainActivity.java`: cannot resolve symbol 'activity'

**Edit**

```
 Localytics.openSession();
 Localytics.upload();

 if (FragmentActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(this.class))
 {
     Localytics.setInAppMessageDisplayActivity(this);
 }
 Localytics.handleTestMode(this.getIntent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...where are you declaring the `activity` variable?

Replace `activity` with `this` in your code. Use `MainActivity.this` if you need to access a reference to your `Activity` from within an inner class.

Fix for the new issue:

```
if (FragmentActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(MainActivity.class))
```

Comment: @I'm now getting 'identifier expected', 'unexpected token' on if (FragmentActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(this.class))